# In the Consumer using the Provider Package how do I set the image to every build in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, build, background, state, flutter-packages

I have wrapped the image field with a getter and setter and called notifyListeners in the setter after updating the underlying field but I can't work out how to set the image to every build.

```
return myModel.image = Image.asset('images/background_image.jpeg', fit: BoxFit.fill);
```

The background image get called and then on a different screen the user can tap on a small image which changes this background image to a different image

```
return myModel.image = Image.asset('images/iceland_background.jpg', fit: BoxFit.fill);
```

Main Screen with the background image:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_background/small_images.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyModel>(
      create: (context) => MyModel(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Title',
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Background Image', style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.black,),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SmallImages()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>
          [
            Positioned.fill(
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Consumer<MyModel>(
                  builder: (context, myModel, child) {
                    return myModel.image = Image.asset('images/background_image.jpeg', fit: BoxFit.fill);
                    // return myValue;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
}

class MyModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  Image _image;
  set image(Image value) {
    _image = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  Image get image => _image;

}
```

Other Screen with the small images that the user clicks on to change the background image:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_background/main.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class SmallImages extends StatefulWidget {
  static int tappedGestureDetector = 1;

  @override
  _SmallImagesState createState() => _SmallImagesState();
}

class _SmallImagesState extends State<SmallImages> {
  List<bool> isSelected;

  void initState() {
    isSelected = [true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myModel = Provider.of<MyModel>(context,listen:true); //default for listen is `true`
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Small Image', style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left, color: Colors.black,),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0.0,
          ),
          body: Material(
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: MaterialApp(
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 1,
                      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      mainAxisSpacing: 0.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 0.0,
                      children: [
                        GridView(
                          gridDelegate:
                          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3,
                            childAspectRatio: MediaQuery
                                .of(context)
                                .size
                                .width /
                                (MediaQuery
                                    .of(context)
                                    .size
                                    .height / 2),
                          ),
                          children: [
                                 GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                      // return myValue;
                                  setState(() {
                                    SmallImages.tappedGestureDetector = 1;
                                  });
                                  print('hi');
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 107,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: SmallImages
                                      .tappedGestureDetector == 1
                                      ? Border.all(
                                      color: Color(0xff2244C7), width: 1.0)
                                      : Border
                                      .all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    'images/nightsky_image.png',
                                  ),
                                ),
                                ),
                            Consumer<MyModel>(
                              builder: (context, myModel, child) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      SmallImages.tappedGestureDetector = 2;
                                    }); // <-- replaced 'tapped' and 'other'
                                    return myModel.image = Image.asset('images/iceland_background.jpg', fit: BoxFit.fill);
                                    },
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 107,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: SmallImages
                                        .tappedGestureDetector == 2
                                        ? Border.all(
                                        color: Color(0xff2244C7), width: 1.0)
                                        : Border
                                        .all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      'images/own_image.png',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                            Consumer<MyModel>(
                              builder: (context, myModel, child) {
                                return GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      SmallImages.tappedGestureDetector = 3;
                                    }); // <-- replaced 'tapped' and 'other'
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 100,
                                    width: 107,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(border: SmallImages
                                        .tappedGestureDetector == 3
                                        ? Border.all(
                                        color: Color(0xff2244C7), width: 1.0)
                                        : Border
                                        .all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                                    child: Image.asset(
                                      'images/iceland_image.png',
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ].toList(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `images/background_image.jpeg` be the image that is used if no other image is selected you should change `return myModel.image = Image.asset('images/background_image.jpeg', fit: BoxFit.fill);` to `return myModel.image ?? Image.asset('images/background_image.jpeg', fit: BoxFit.fill);`

What the `??` does here is it checks if `myModel.image` is null, if it is null than it uses the fallback background image and if it is not null it will use `myModel.image` as the image.

Btw in the onTap you don’t need the return so change that to `myModel.image = Image.asset('images/iceland_background.jpg', fit: BoxFit.fill);`